# Use of Utils.java file

Tags: java, api, servlets, file-io, bufferedreader

I have this Java servlet API file and in it is a class called utils.java . I can't quite figure out what the use of this piece of code is in the API. This is my first time working on APIs so any help in understanding this would be appreciated.

```
package implementation;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

public class Utils {
    
    public static String getBody(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {

        String body = null;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
            if (inputStream != null) {
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                char[] charBuffer = new char[128];
                int bytesRead = -1;
                while ((bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(charBuffer)) > 0) {
                    stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            } else {
                stringBuilder.append("");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }

        body = stringBuilder.toString();
        return body;
    }
}
```

And then in other servlets it has been called like this: `String req = Utils.getBody(request);`

Can someone please explain the working?

Comment: I realize you did not write Utils.java, but that file is a bad example.  No one should ever, for any reason, name a file Utils.java.  It should have been called BodyExtractor.java or TextBodyExtractor.java.  “Utils” is about as descriptive as “SomeClass.”  Someday when you write your own APIs, I hope you will not use the name “Utils.”

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of this method is to read the request body and return it as a `String`.   Basically, it gets hold of the request's input stream, wraps it as a reader (which converts to characters), reads characters from it and appends them to `StringBuilder`.  When it reaches the end of the stream it closes it, and returns the builder's contents as a `String`.

The code *could* be simplified a bit.  Indeed, in Java 8+, the core code could be replaced with

```
return bufferedReader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"))
```

The clunky handling of the streams could be simplified using Java 7+ *try with resources*.

The method simplifies to this:

```
public static String getBody(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    try (InputStream is = request.getInputStream();
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))) {
        return br.lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
    }
}
```

There are a couple of issues with this:

1. It is using the platform default character set to decode the input rather than the character set that *may* have been specified in the HTTP request header.  That problem can be solved by using `request.getReader()` instead of `request.getInputStream()`.
2. It is converting the original end-of-line sequences into the platform's standard end-of-line sequences.
3. If the request's body is extremely large, converting it into a `String` could fill up the heap, and lead to OOMEs.  That could be used as a Denial of Service attack.  If this is a concern, the code needs to be more defensive ... or you need to set a request size limit at the web container level.

Comment: `bufferedReader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining())` would remove the linebreaks though compared to the original.

Comment: Good point.   Fixing.

Comment: Since Java 11 you can use `request.getInputStream().transferTo` to write to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, then use its `toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` method to get a String out of it (or any other encoding if necessary.